# How expensive is an AWS RDS 'transfer out' cost?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have a social network website hosted on AWS. Am I going to get charged at all for RDS ‘transfer cost’ (since RDS will connect to EC2 through AWS)? Does that mean I only need to pay for EC2 ‘transfer cost’? How expensive can “database” bandwidth compared with “image” bandwidth?

Really appreciate any input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are data-transfer charges from RDS to ec2 instance as well but it varies based on your setup , According to AWS docs

- Data transferred between Amazon RDS and Amazon EC2 Instances in the same Availability Zone is priced as follows

  - Using a private IP address is free.
  - Using a public or Elastic IP address is $0.01 per GB
- Data transferred between Availability Zones for replication of Multi-AZ deployments is free.
- Amazon RDS DB Instances outside VPC: For data transferred between an Amazon EC2 instance and Amazon RDS DB Instance in different Availability Zones of the same Region, there is no Data Transfer charge for traffic in or out of the Amazon RDS DB Instance. You are only charged for the Data Transfer in or out of the Amazon EC2 instance, and standard Amazon EC2 Regional Data Transfer charges apply ($.01 per GB in/out).
- Amazon RDS DB Instances inside VPC: For data transferred between an Amazon EC2 instance and Amazon RDS DB Instance in different Availability Zones of the same Region, Amazon EC2 Regional Data Transfer charges apply on both sides of transfer.

You can check what is your setup and for complete list of pricing refer https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/.